# Python can't open file in autostart

Tags: python, registry

When I start my program in autostart I get the Error `[Errno13] Permission denied` when it should open the file.
When I then start the program manually it all works and my program opens the file. I autostart my program as registry key in Windows

I use `with open('save.macros', mode='rb') as f` to open the file. The file is in the same directory and the program also noticed the file but cant open it on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of occurs error on running your file in python,

1. File path is not exact
2. wrong File's extension
3. difference for windows and linux path slash (windows => \ , linux => /)
4. or `save.macros` file is using in another process

and make your you placed that `save.macros` file in same place with your python code.

and try this :

```
with open('.\save.macros', mode='rb') as f
```

Comment: Found it. I had a relative path with having only ```'save.macros'``` I've made a folder in AppData and referenced that. Now it works!